# How to use my logged in user in other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to backend programming with C# MVC, and I created a login system which works.

```
public ActionResult Login(LogingInViewModel Login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = _context.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == Login.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.Password== Crypto.SHA256(Login.Password))
            {
                user.Token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _context.SaveChanges();
                HttpCookie tokenCookie = new HttpCookie("token")
                {
                    Value=user.Token,
                    HttpOnly=true

                };

                tokenCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

                Response.Cookies.Add(tokenCookie);
                return RedirectToAction("index","Home",user);
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Wrong Email or Password");
    }

    LoginViewModel model1 = new LoginViewModel
    {
        Login = Login
    };

    return View("~/Views/Login/Index.cshtml", model1);
}
```

but I have no idea how I can use this object in all my other pages/controllers or even Shared/Layout to display username and profile picture up top.
I looked up online and tried some solutions, but they didn't work like

```
@if (Model != null)  {  <span>@Model.Fullname</span>}
        else {   <span>Log in</span> }
```

and of course since I can not send the object it is null.

Comment: You can use a session with any information and maybe you deen lerarn about Claims and Identity

Comment: Can't you use `HttpContext.CurrentUser.Username`?